# Why are collaborators allowed to create a branch then make pull requests, while contributors need to fork, clone, then branch to make pull requests?

Tags: github

I was learning about different GitHub workflows and I ran into this question that I could not find the answer to. What is the reasoning for adding this functionality in GitHub instead of allowing everybody to branch directly from origin and contribute to the project that way?

Comment: That is not a git question. It is a _github_ question. Git allows operations to be carried out on repositories _locally_ involving remote repos if needed... but you are the master and commander of your local repo.

Comment: @eftshift0 Thank you, I have updated the tags to this question correspondingly so that it is more accessible to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the workflows depends on the access to the original repository.  In both cases, in order to submit code, you generally still need to clone the repository so you can work on it locally, although you can avoid this if you really want to.

To illustrate the differnce, I am a collaborator on the Git LFS repository, but a contributor to the libgit2 repository.  Because I'm a project maintainer, I have permission to push branches to the Git LFS repository, so I can, if I choose, push a branch from my local clone to the main repository and then open a pull request.  I usually choose not to, preferring to work from my own personal fork instead, but I can if I choose, and I do so in certain cases, such as when creating release branches.

However, I don't have permission to push data to the libgit2 repository, since I'm not a collaborator.  If I try, I'll be refused.  This is because even though I've contributed, I don't do so regularly, and I'm not responsible for the project.  It wouldn't make sense to grant me the ability to push branches to the main repository, since I could push branches that interfere with others' branches, delete branches, or push branches that conflict with project rules and requirements, and other users could be misled into thinking my branches were officially sanctioned when they were not.

So in this case, I need to create a fork of the repository so I have a space that I do control to work on the code as I see fit, and then submit a pull request.  The maintainers of libgit2 then can work with me to make sure my code meets project standards and then incorporate it.  If they decide not to take it, then nobody will be misled into thinking my code is part of the original project.

All of this is specific to GitHub and similar systems that use pull requests.  Git doesn't know anything about pull requests in this sense (although it does have a similarly named feature that's completely different).

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that 'collaborators' means people that you know/trust to work on your projects (e.g.: your teammate/work colleague/etc) usually on proprietary project or college/uni assignment project, while 'contributors' means some open source developer that you might not personally acquainted with.

One reason that comes to mind is that you don't really want to trust your project to someone that you don't personally know, but you still want them to be able to make/suggest/contribute to your open source project.

In github action (like gitlab runner or bitbucket pipeline, basically feature to run scripts inside github's container on push/events), there is a feature called 'github action secrets'. In this feature you can save passwords/ssh-keys etc to be used by the container/action (e.g.: you want to make action 'on push to master branch, please run commands to push those changes to my deployment server via ssh, in which the username/password/ssh-key is stored inside github action secrets).

Github action secrets will not be copied when someone forked your repo. But it will still be available on branches. Indicating that only people that you trust should be given write access to your repo.

On the other hand, people who forked your repo can have their own github action secrets, that you as the 'real' owner of the forked repo CANNOT read.